# QGIS Raster Calculator with ComboBox

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am working on QGIS plugin using Raster calculator. I have five different raster.

```
self.dlg.show()

result = self.dlg.exec_()

if result:          
    input_raster = str(self.dlg.comboBox.currentText())
    output_raster = self.dlg.lineEdit.text()
   
    parameters = {'INPUT_A' : input_raster,
        'BAND_A' : 1,
        'FORMULA' : '(A/100)',
        'OUTPUT' : output_raster}
        'OUTPUT' : output_raster}

    processing.runAndLoadResults('gdal:rastercalculator', parameters)
```

The above code works, but how can I make my raster calculator calculate the five raster file from the comboBox?